# Placeholder TextBox in C# WPF - Can't bind the DepedencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to build my a TextBox with some variable placeholder text.
But the property "PlaceholderText" ist not used in the Visual Brush - Label.

The placeholder text in `<Label Content="{Binding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="LightGray" />` is always empty.

When I use the binding out of the , the binding works. I tried to use the binding as Text: `<TextBox Text="{Binding PlaceholderText}" >` and it works perfectly.

Why not inside the `<VisualBrush><Label Content="...">...`

I hope someone can help me.

```xml
<TextBox x:Class="CustomerPro.Common.Controls.PlaceholderTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomerPro.Common.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="800" Name="phTextBox">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <VisualBrush x:Key="PHBoxBackground" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Label Content="{Binding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="LightGray" />
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PHBoxBackground}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PHBoxBackground}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

```cs
    public partial class PlaceholderTextBox : TextBox
    {
        #region PlaceholderText

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the PlaceholderText which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        public String PlaceholderText
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identified the PlaceholderText dependency property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceholderText", typeof(string), typeof(PlaceholderTextBox), new PropertyMetadata("Type some Text"));

        #endregion


        public PlaceholderTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.phTextBox.DataContext = this;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way but you could try `<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TextBox}}, Path=PlaceholderText}" Foreground="LightGray" />`

Comment: As a note, when you explicitly set the DataContext property of a control (be it to this or some private view model), any standard DataContext-based Bindings will no longer work. E.g. `<local:PlaceholderTextBox PlaceholderText="{Binding SomeText}"/>` won't work, becaue the SomeText property is expected in the current DataContex of the control. You should remove the assignment and use a Binding as suggested by Sajith, which could be a bit simplified to `Content="{Binding PlaceholderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}`.

Comment: Or use an ElementName Binding like `Content="{Binding PlaceholderText, ElementName=phTextBox}"`

Comment: Hi SajithSageer and Clemens, I tried both variants, but both unfortunately doesn't work. No placeholder text will be shown. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind by "`ElementName`" but that is *more elaborated* inside the `Resources`:

```
<Label 
    Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference phTextBox}, Path=PlaceholderText}"
            Foreground="LightGray" />
```

See also [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6df77aab-9acb-42e5-83e1-891322026b32/wpf-how-to-use-binding-by-elementname-in-resources?forum=wpf).